# Android Market Developer Console

Tags: android, logging, console, google-play

I tried to google common info about subject, but i really can't find some basic description about this feature.

I have some questions about how does it work, what kind of info i can get from it, when info is being posted there, does messages from Log.v() are posted there

Comment: Sorry what is the 'Google market developer console'? Please specify or link a website/screenshot

Comment: I heared about it on stackoverflow - it's some tool to read reports from my apps^ i think

Comment: I know what you mean. It's not really a console. It won't display Log out. It will display stacktraces if you program encounters a ForceClose and the user presses the 'report' button.

Comment: Made it an answer, so you can get your accept rating up :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really a console.

It won't display Log out.

It will display stacktraces if you program encounters a ForceClose and the user presses the 'report' button.